# Make UI changes mid function in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift, reload

i'm trying go make a UIViewcontroller in which i update some files for my application. im trying to show the progress of the update but it seems that as im updating and make changes to certain IBOutlets, they wont actually change appearance until my function is finished. can somebody help me with this?
here is a part of my Update() function

```
for person in allContacts {
        if person.pictureName != "#" {
            infoLabel.text = "Downloading picture of " + person.name
            person.picture = DBManager.downloadPicture(person.pictureName)
            infoLabel.text = "Saving picture of " + person.name
            DBManager.savePicture(person.picture, pictureName: person.pictureName)
        }

        progressBar.progress += oneProgressBarFragment
    }
```

the progress bar wont update until it reaches the end of the Update() function and then it shows that it is 100% completed. is there some way i can redraw the UI so that the progress bar gets updated after every picture download?

Comment: You are doing one of two very wrong things. Either you are performing time-consuming (downloading) code synchronously on the main thread, or you are talking to the interface from a background thread. Either way, you have a major threading problem. You need to rethink your whole approach here.

Comment: @matt I am performing time consuming tasks on the main thread. How would you go about doing this? thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: I would learn how to download things properly, i.e. asynchronously. Okay, well, actually, I _know_ how to download things properly. I'm saying _you_ should learn to download things properly. :)

Comment: The thing is, you are relying on some third-party hidden class called DBManager. I have no idea what that is, or whether it can be used asynchronously. So I can't give you specifics, beyond telling you what I would do, which is to use NSURLSession - asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Should do the downloading asynchronously and have some other way of checking progress.